# How can I generate a code coverage report for a failed Jenkins build

Tags: perl, unit-testing, jenkins, code-coverage

I'm trying to build my Perl project with Jenkins in such a way that I get a JUnit report and a test coverage report. I'm having trouble getting my code report when my build fails. Here's how the build is configured:

```
perl Build.PL; ./Build;
cover -delete;
PERL5OPT=-MDevel::Cover prove -b --formatter=TAP::Formatter::JUnit t/ > junit.xml;
cover;
```

The problem with this is when `prove` exits with a non-zero status (i.e. when some of my tests fail) the `cover` command never runs; the build aborts, reporting:

```
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Is there a good way to get a test coverage report, even when some of the tests are currently failing?

Comment: No, `cover` processes the `cover_db`, which is the information about which lines of code have been executed, with which truth values, etc.. This is interesting information, regardless of whether or not all the tests pass.

Comment: So it's just a matter of *not* exiting on error?

Comment: Or why not run cover before you run the tests?

Comment: It's a matter of not exiting prematurely. I still want the build to be marked as a failure, but `cover` needs to run after the tests.

Comment: I clearly don't understand 'cover' very well... I don't understand how it's important for it to run *after* the tests, but that it can succeed if the tests don't.  But I'll leave that for you and whoever can provide an answer to worry about... I'm clearly out of my league :)

Comment: The 3rd line in my example runs the tests. The `-MDevel::Cover` bit means that as the tests execute (some pass, some fail.. doesn't really matter), it records information about _which lines of source code are executed_. The idea is that you can look at this information to assess the quality of your tests; in other words, you can see how much of your source code is _covered_ by your tests. As-is, it's not human-readable; the `cover` command just makes it pretty.

Comment: It's just a shell script right? It should be pretty easy to find posts here about how to capture and delay failures in shell scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the `cover` part into a [Post Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) task so it always executed and you wouldn't need any additional logic to check status as you go along

Comment: Perfect! I was looking for a post-build option, and was disappointed that it didn't exist. Didn't think to look in the plugin library though :)